# Rails, Prawn PDF and Line Breaks

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, line-breaks, prawn, split

I am populating a table in Prawn like so:

```
@rows.map do |row|
  cell_1 = row.name
  cell_2 = row.description
  cols = [cell_1, cell_2]
end
```

Client wants to be able to add line breaks in description(cell_2) field. I add "This is big description \n now i should have new line". But it just outputs the "\n" as text?

But if I hard code text in cell 2 like so:

```
@rows.map do |row|
  cell_1 = row.name
  cols = [cell_1, "I am big description \n now i have new line"]
end
```

If I do that it does break it onto a second line. So how can I get variable 'cell_2' to do line breaks? I've tried using cell_2.split before putting cell_2 into the "cols" array but doesn't work it still outputs the "\n" as text.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong are most appreciated.

Ruby 2.1.2
Rails 4.1.1

Comment: Is the text coming from a web request (e.g. a form in a browser)? A `\n` only represents a newline in your Ruby _source_, if it is part of a request it is just a literal slash followed by an `n`. If you are using a text `input` field you could change it to a `textarea` and allow the user to add literal newlines, otherwise you would have to parse the string yourself.

Comment: Well it is an input field yes. Form gets saved, then user clicks a download as PDF button, so the info is coming from database by PDF stage. So changing to textarea is only way to do it? Thanks for help.

Comment: Make sure you're using "" instead of ''. So, if you can split your cell2 into an array and then join them with "\n" it should work. So, let's say you're getting something in cell2 like "This is a long, description" you could cell2.split(',').join("\n"). That's a stupid example because they're not going to have a comma there, but you could tokenize that cell2 string however you want. The point is to make sure that you join your string parts with "\n", not '\n'.